# Mix regular imports and static imports in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-import

By default, Intellij Idea separates regular imports and static imports. Like

```
 import com.a;
 import com.b;

 import static com.a.C.foo;
```

What I want is placing it together. Like

```
 import com.a;
 import static com.a.C.foo;
 import com.b;
```

How can I configure such layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a `Layout static imports separately` option in Settings/Code Style/Java/Import Tab (you might have to scroll tabs horizontally for this).

[image]