# Organize static imports before before import in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-import

I am new to IntelliJ. I am currently facing an issue where I want to organize the static imports before the general import (Similar to the coding guidelines we have in eclipse). I could not find the setting to do so. Not having this would create unnecessary modification in each commit as developers in my team use either Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Thanks

Comment: This might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343505/mix-regular-imports-and-static-imports-in-intellij-idea :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings > Code Style > Java > "Imports" Tab > Import Layout (near the bottom)

More info at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-style-java.html#d48088e1314

Answer (score 1):

Use [Eclipse Code Formatter plugin.](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546?pr=idea)